# MySQLの更新にいて

Tags: mysql

以下のデータがあったとき、
親idが同じのとき、金額がNULLのものは、NULLでないものに書き換えるには
どうしたらいいのでしょうか？
ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。
この状態から
親id,子id,金額
A001,001,100
A001,002,NULL
A002,001,NULL
A002,002,200
A002,003,NULL
↓
親id,子id,金額
A001,001,100
A001,002,100
A002,001,200
A002,002,200
A002,003,200
にもっていきたい

Answer (score 0):

金額がNULLでないレコードが、各親idについて一つしか存在しないなら以下でできます。
テーブル名、カラム名は適切なものに置き換えてください。

```
UPDATE `テーブル名` table_a, `テーブル名` table_b
SET table_a.金額 = table_b.金額
WHERE table_a.親id = table_b.親id
AND table_a.金額 IS NULL
AND table_b.金額 IS NOT NULL;
```